# Wrong Color received from method

Tags: java, swing, colors, return, switch-statement

Why is this code not returning right `Color`? Everytime, it is executed with `name="YELLOW"` or `name="RED"`, it returns `Color.WHITE`.

```
Color recieveColor(String name)
{
    Color color=new Color(255,0,0);
    switch(name)
    {
        case "YELLOW":
        {
            color=Color.YELLOW;
        }
        case "RED":
        {
           color=Color.RED;
        }
        case "WHITE":
        {
            color=Color.WHITE;
        }
    }
    return color;
}
```

Comment: After each `case` use `break` statement. `Break` just exits from `switch-case` statement

Comment: Avoid initializing the color variable with `=new Color(255,0,0);` and add a default case instead: `default: { color = Color.RED; break; }`.

Comment: use break or you recieve white always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you don't have `break`.
Also you can put default in case your color name does not match

```
 switch (name) {
        case "YELLOW":
            color = Color.YELLOW;
            break;
        case "RED":
            color = Color.RED;
            break
        case "WHITE":
            color = Color.WHITE;
            break;
        default: 
            color = Color.YELLOW;
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use `break` in `switch case`. `break` needs to exit from `case`.

```
   switch (name) {
        case "YELLOW":
            color = Color.YELLOW;
            break;
        case "RED":
            color = Color.RED;
            break
        case "WHITE":
            color = Color.WHITE;
            break;
    }
```

Else you will always have color white

`Java` [switch cases](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you do not have a `break`; after the `color` has been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is answered a few times (using the `break` keyword, to omit fallthrough), I'd like to give you some advice on the matter by using `return`. This omits the entire problem: it can't go wrong with `returns.

```
switch (name) {
    case "YELLOW": 
        return Color.YELLOW;
    case "RED":
        return Color.RED;
    case "WHITE":
        return Color.WHITE;
    default:
         return Color.BLACK;
}
```

Comment: why? why this approach should be used?

Comment: @M.S. Because this way you can't make the mistake you made by forgetting the `break`. Also, the method should return the color, so it's useless to save the color to a variable and then return it by the end of the method. Why not do it within the switch statement? Short anwser: this approach is less prone to small mistakes.